# How mass change can be converted to energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, mass-energy

Some gas with initial mass $m_{1}$ was put in a container under high pressure and temperature. After some time its mass became a bit smaller ($m_2$). Additionally, some energy was released and it was accumulated.

Assume that the above is a possible process. There is no additional information on exactly what kind of process took place and if it is possible in real life, so we just assume that the mass became smaller and energy was released for some reason.

How can we calculate the amount of energy released knowing only $m_1$ and $m_2$ ($\delta m$)?

I doubt we can use $mc^2$ or can we?

Comment: Please don't re-post [closed questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/804854/44126).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the energy released, just look at the mass difference because according to the question you have given, there is both a starting mass and a final mass, so it is possible that not all of the mass was actually converted.

So to find the energy released, you can do Mass difference equal to=m1-m2, to get how much mass was lost. Then multiply this Mass difference with c^2 to get total amount of energy gained. So essentially the formula would be E=(m1-m2)c^2 because not all of the mass is converted to energy.

Most likely reason this probably happened is probably fission or fusion because normally using E=mc^2 for combustion questions is not neccesary, and if it was an antimatter annihilation then there probably won't be a final mass, because usually they make the question in such a way that all of the antimatter is used for complete annihilation.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't give me the correct answer for my original problem that was closed in stachexchange, I assumed that I do not understand correctly something... physics. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/804854/how-long-phone-can-operate-using-energy-released-from-hydrogen

Answer (score 0):

> I doubt we can just use mc2

You can. That's the answer.  Any procedure giving another answer would have to account for the missing/excess mass-energy.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't give me the correct answer for my original problem that was closed, I assumed that I do not understand correctly something...

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/804854/how-long-phone-can-operate-using-energy-released-from-hydrogen

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.